# In LC-3, how can I access the first data point if the amount of data varies?

Tags: assembly, memory, memory-address, lc3

The data starts at x3001 but the amount of lines of data will vary so I'm not sure how to access the first data point if isn't a fixed offset from the rest of my code.

Comment: If you know the absolute address, use it instead of addressing relative to the program counter!  Or just use labels and let the assembler calculate the distance.

Comment: @PeterCordes, LC-3 doesn't have absolute addressing as an addressing mode.

Comment: @ErikEidt: I think you mean it doesn't have absolute *direct* addressing, since your answer shows a way to use a numeric absolute address via indirection.  So it's not that inconvenient to put a numeric literal somewhere where you can get an LC-3 assembler to make an instruction that uses it.

Comment: @PeterCordes, yes of course, no "absolute *direct* addressing".  Still not totally clear what the querent is asking.  Given a branch to start, the first data item would always be at x3001... no matter amount of "lines of data".

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample that accesses data, copying the #65 at x3001 to x3002.  The #65 at x3001 is accessed directly, whereas the x3002 is accessed indirectly.

```
       .ORIG x3000
       BR START

DATA1, .FILL #65
DATA2, .FILL #-1

START, LD R0, DATA1
       STI R0, PTR1
       HALT

PTR1,  .FILL x3002
       .END
```